# How to access Photoshop pattern source file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

Is it possible to have access to the source file of each pattern you have inside Photoshop? A pattern is a squared piece of some artwork that is repeated according to the settings you choose. How could I get direct access to the 1 piece of that specific pattern so I can manipulate it or make it usable for web?

My goal is to have direct access to the pattern itself outside of Photoshop, like a `.jpg` file or so. I tried accessing Photoshops folder and located the pattern folder but I can´t see any customized pattern I created there, where does Photoshop store the patterns you create? I only saw `.pat` files there. Is there a way to access directly each pattern separated as a single file?

Please someone help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct access.

### However....

First make certain **Tool Tips** is **on** in the **Preferences**.

[image]

Now, bring up the **Pattern selector** (here I used the Pattern Overlay Layer Style), and hover your cursor over a pattern until the tool tip pops up....

[image]

You'll see the pixel dimensions of the tile there. In this case 400x400px.

Now create a **new document** at those **dimensions** and **fill it** with that **pattern**. You'll have a **single tile of the pattern** which you can then save as any image format you want.

Comment: Great solution! Not the perfect and easy way but it will work! Thanks a lot for your time taking the screenshots and answering! Really appreciated.